# Setup cocos2d-x application through visual studio 2010 project template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to setup an application on Windows 7 using Cocos2D-x.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Cocos2d-x_Application_Wizard_for_Visual_Studio_User_Guide).

I did the following:

1. Built the library running Build-win32.bat script. Works.
2. Installed VS2010 project template. Works.
3. Run successfully all test programs.
4. Created a new cocos2D-x project through the installed template. Works

When I compile the Hello World application I have the follwing errors:

```
error C1083: impossible to open inclusion file 'CCstdC.h' No such file or directory
error C1083: impossible to open inclusion file 'cocos2d.h' No such file or directory
```

It's a wrong include path.

I could fix it by manually modifying include path but since I'm creating project through the template I-d like to solve this, possibly not having to modify paths manually for each new project I'll create.

Did anyone ever had the same issue?Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved opening the cocos2dx library solution and add to it a new project through VS template wizard.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I setup cocos2dx projects like this:

1. create an empty win32 app in VS
2. open the folder contains your .sln file (your solution folder)
3. open the cocos2dx package (i.e. cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.12.0.zip) with 7z or something
4. drag cocos2dx, and optionally CocosDenshion,  Box2D, etc. to your solution folder
5. add cocos2dx project (cocos2dx\proj.win32\cocos2d-win32.vcxproj) into your solution
6. go to your project's properties, select C/C++->General, add the following entries to your Additional Include Directories option:

   **..\cocos2dx; ..\cocos2dx\include; ..\cocos2dx\platform; ..\cocos2dx\platform\win32; ..\cocos2dx\platform\third_party\win32\OGLES**

and **..\CocosDenshion\include** if you're using the SimpleAudioEngine

1. in the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies option, add libcocos2d.lib, and libCocosDenshion.lib if you use the audio engine; in the Linker->General->Additional Library Directories option, add $(OutDir)
2. go to the Configuration Properties->General->Output Directory option, set it to $(SolutionDir)\build\
3. open the project property for cocos2d library, go to the Configuration Properties->General->Output Directory, set it to $(SolutionDir)\build\, also do that to the rest of the libraries you included.

All set, you're ready to go.

Comment: Don't forget to add the CocosDenshion project to the solution as well. That was the reason why I couldn't compile my app at first.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that template is not that useful. I believe that in a previous version of cocos2d-x (the one that tutorial is based on) the paths were absolute, and referenced the `cocos2dx`, `cocosdenshion` projects directly.

Now, as they're relative (`..\..\cocos2dx`), and they are not copied to the solution directory when a project is created, it just doesn't work.

You could obviously fix the paths (as you suggested) but my suggestion is: copy the HelloWorld project and use it as a template. The solution structure is much better than the one in the template as it's already prepared for iOS, win32 and Android. Trust me, can't get any easier than that.

Now, here's the catch: if you copy the HelloWorld project to a sibling folder, you're done, as all the references are already setup. If you want to copy to other place you'll have to also copy `cocos2dx`, `cocosdenshion` along, leaving the target structure like:

```
target_path\cocos2dx
target_path\cocosdenshion
target_path\Copy_of_Hello_World
```